# D3: How to construct HeatMap using local JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to construct Day/Night HeatMap using dynamic data stored in a JSON object but could not succeed.
I am able to do using tsv file stored locally.

Here is code sample.
I just want to read from "data" variable which is a json.

I am referring this: http://bl.ocks.org/ianyfchang/8119685

Comment: Without any code/data, we cannot properly help you. What is not working? _I could not succeed_ is not very informative.

Comment: //This is working:
d3.tsv("data.tsv",
    function(d) {
        return {
            row: +d.row_idx,
            col: +d.col_idx,
            value: +d.magnitude
        };
    },
    function(error, data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
        .domain([0, buckets - 1, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.value;
        })])
        .range(colors);
    .......

});

//But I want to do using local variable
// data= JSON.stringify(jsondata);

Comment: Not in the comments! Update your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't mistake your question,

**you want to know how to transfer a Json file or Javascript Object into D3 data**

right?

I don't know whether you've read the chapter about `d3.tsv` in the documents.

TSV works just like CSV, the only difference is the separator.

As you may notice this fragment in the sample code:

```
d3.tsv("data_heatmap.tsv",
function(d) {
  return {
    row:   +d.row_idx,
    col:   +d.col_idx,
    value: +d.log2ratio
  };
},
function(error, data) {...}
```

Here in the doc, [Wiki>Reference>csv](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#csv)

> d3.csv(url[[, accessor], callback])
>
> Issues an HTTP GET request for the comma-separated values (CSV) file at the specified url.
>
> ...
>
> An optional accessor function may be specified, which is then passed to d3.csv.parse;

The fragment I quoted above is just the accessor which turns TSV data into Javascript Object.

In other words, D3 won't handle TSV or CSV formed data, it only handles parsed Javascript Object.

And the function callback: that's `function(err,data){...}` in the fragment.
It handles the data analyzing and graph drawing.

**SO WHAT SHOULD WE DO WITH AN OBJECT?**

Just pass it to the `callback` function you invoke in `d3.tsv(file,accessor,callback)`.

It will work the same way as you invoke a TSV file.

---

HOPE IT HELPS.

Comment: I want to pass object from local variable not from external file. I am collecting data dynamically. So how can I pass a variable instead of file.

Comment: @Faiyaz . As I've explained, when you handle a tsv, you get the file, parse it and pipe the parsed data into the callback function. Now you just pipe your data into the callback function. If it needs parsing, parse it manually.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this http://cal-heatmap.com/

I had use this many time, and it works very well and it is simple to use.